# Storing multiple results from for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration, repeat

I am using a for loop to perform repeatability analysis on subsets of my data. I am struggling to find a function that will store the results of my for loop in a data frame, because the repeatability analysis output gives R, Standard Error, Confidence Interval, and p-values. I would like to only store R and CI values.

Here is my code:

```
p<-10000

for(i in 1:P){
  newdf<-df[df$ID %in% sample(unique(df$ID), 16), ]
  m1<-rpt(Behaviour~Temperature+(1|ID),grname="ID",data=newdf,datatype="Gaussian",nboot=1000,npermut=1000)
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a numeric vector to store R and CI values :

```
p<-10000
R_value <- numeric(length = p)
CI_value <- numeric(length = p)

for(i in 1:P) {
  newdf<-df[df$ID %in% sample(unique(df$ID), 16), ]
  m1<- rptR::rpt(Behaviour~Temperature+(1|ID),grname="ID",data=newdf,
                 datatype="Gaussian",nboot=1000,npermut=1000)
  R_value[i] <- m1$R
  CI_value[i] <- m1$CI
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but unfortunately the R_value and CI_value are just returning a string of 0's! Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you run the loop? When we initialise `R_value` and `CI_value`, they are initialised to 0 but after running the loop there should be some value.

Comment: I ran the loop, and then called R_value() and CI_value() afterwards as no values appeared after running the loop..

Comment: You should do `R_value` and `CI_value`. `()` is used for functions. It seems to work with example shared in `?rpt` page. If it doesn't work for your data, can you share your data?

Comment: It seems that this works when I run the repeatability analysis outside of the for loop, but 0's are still generated when I use the for loop. Any suggestions on where I might me going wrong with the loop?

Comment: @LizzieYarwood  Did you run the above code exactly as is?  Did you receive any errors?  I had to change the P in the for loop to be lowercase, then it worked for me.