# For Loop List Not Storing Values

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, repeat

I have a data set of behaviours performed by individuals repeatedly at different temperatures, e.g.:

```
  ID          Test   Behaviour     Temperature
 A12.4.2      ONE     8.64            4
 A12.4.2      TWO     7.63            5
 A6.3.3       ONE     1.81            3
 A6.3.3       TWO     2.47            9
 B12.4.1      ONE     1.17            12
 B12.4.1      TWO     3.96            2
 E9.4.2       ONE     13.04           13
 E9.4.2       TWO     9.51            6
 ...
```

I use the following code to randomly subset that data set, and then run repeatability analysis on the subset, producing R values and CI values from the repeatability analysis at the end.

```
P<-10000

R_value<-numeric(length=P)
CI_value<-numeric(length=P)
for(i in 1:P){
  newdata<-Data[Data$ID %in% sample(unique(Data$ID), 16), ]
  m1<-rptR::rpt(((Behaviour))~Temperature+(1|ID),grname="ID",data=newdata,datatype="Gaussian",nboot=1000,npermut=1000)
  R_value[i] <- m1$R
  CI_value[i] <- m1$CI
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. When I call `R_value` or `CI_value`, I am greeted with a string of 0's. Upon calling `newdata` or `m1`, R tells me that the object cannot be found.

Where I run the repeatability analysis outside of the for loop, everything turns out fine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what does `Data` look like?. Also, this looks like a duplicate from your question a couple of hours ago... ?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing multiple results from for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894160/storing-multiple-results-from-for-loop)

Comment: Hi Wimpel, my question is different from that posted a couple of hours ago in that I have tried the code suggested to me and whilst it resolved some of my issues, I am having new issues with this code.

Comment: Lizzie, it's a good idea to take the code that's in the loop, and instead of running the loop,  set `i <- 1`. Now run each line of the code and see if you get the expected result for `newdata` and `m1`

Comment: Hi Allan, I do get the expected results from doing as you suggested.

Comment: @LizzieYarwood and if you do your loop with `for(i in 1)` this is logically identical. Does it give you different results?

Comment: @AllanCameron unfortunately it does give different results. Where I received expected results when not using the loop, I am now met with the 0's of the unfilled ``` R_value``` and ```CI_value``` vectors. I believe it has something to do with ```newdata``` and ```m1``` not being recognised, although I am not given an error message to say so until I call upon them after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running. There was an error message in the `sample` which I have changed to
`sample(unique(Data$ID), 4)`. And then it runs. You probably could also have added replace like so `sample(unique(Data$ID), 16, replace = TRUE)`, this works, too.  I have also reduced the numbers in `rboot` and in `npermut`.

```r
library(rptR)

Data <- read.table(text = "
ID          Test   Behaviour     Temperature
 A12.4.2      ONE     8.64            4
 A12.4.2      TWO     7.63            5
 A6.3.3       ONE     1.81            3
 A6.3.3       TWO     2.47            9
 B12.4.1      ONE     1.17            12
 B12.4.1      TWO     3.96            2
 E9.4.2       ONE     13.04           13
 E9.4.2       TWO     9.51            6
                   ", header =T)


Data

#>        ID Test Behaviour Temperature
#> 1 A12.4.2  ONE      8.64           4
#> 2 A12.4.2  TWO      7.63           5
#> 3  A6.3.3  ONE      1.81           3
#> 4  A6.3.3  TWO      2.47           9
#> 5 B12.4.1  ONE      1.17          12
#> 6 B12.4.1  TWO      3.96           2
#> 7  E9.4.2  ONE     13.04          13
#> 8  E9.4.2  TWO      9.51           6
P<-10
R_value<-numeric(length=P)
CI_value<-numeric(length=P)

for(i in 1:P){
  newdata<-Data[Data$ID %in% sample(unique(Data$ID), 4), ]
  m1<-rptR::rpt(((Behaviour))~Temperature+(1|ID), grname="ID", data=newdata, datatype="Gaussian", nboot=10, npermut=10)
  R_value[i] <- m1$R
  CI_value[i] <- m1$CI
}


R_value
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 0.8324396
CI_value
#>  [1] 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95
```